# Modeling of the OPC UA Address Space

Tags: opc, opc-ua

My situation is as follows:

My raspberry pi is connected to several sensors (3 temperature sensors, 1 humidity sensor, 2 current sensors and 1 pressure sensor). The sensors are measuring values from an engine and I am currently trying to develop an address space model for my OPC UA server which will run on the raspberry pi.

So far, so good.  As I have read through many tutorials by now, modeling the address space is like developing a class diagram with inheritance. That is why I defined an EngineType (<- ObjectType) and instantiated an object from it (which is called “Engine”). The EngineType currently defines variables (like member variables in OOP) for each sensor value.

But here is my question:

As each sensor has its own type (temperature, pressure, humidity, …) , name and value type (celsius, mbar, humidity,..) and value range, I think it would not be bad if I define a SensorType (ObjectType node) and consequently, ObjectTypes for each type of sensor: TempSensorType, HumiditySensorType and so on… .

So according to my suggestion, the Engine Object would end up with a bunch of members which are all instantiated from object types.

Is this best practice in OPC UA or too complicated? Is there a more elegant way to solve this? I hope I explained my situation clearly enough.

I appreciate any help or suggestion you can possibly give me! Thank you so much in advance, if you have any questions concerning the situation I described above, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

The design sounds reasonable to me.

Even if a client has no understanding of the model in advance they should still be able to make sense of and consume the data, which I think is an important quality to keep in mind as you design.

What I would avoid is using custom *DataType*s for your values because this requires a client advanced enough to read the DataTypeDictionary from the server and be able to decode and encode custom structures dynamically based on the dictionary contents.

Comment: hey kevin, thank you so much for your feedback. Is integrating the SensorType and the inheriting "humiditySensorType","TempSensorType" .. classs a good idea then? Or should I just define the EngineType class with all sensor values as variables?

Comment: To a client the instances will look the same either way. It will only add some complexity to your server and to any clients that might be using the types or code generated from the types.